# How to show an error message if a (html) file is not parsed by PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing, if-statement

So I have a html file including some php code. As I offer it for downloading (because it is in an open source project) you may imagine that some people try to access the file directly, e.g. by drag and dropping it into their browser.

Obviously this is not correct and may cause errors, because the PHP code cannot be executed. So most browsers just ignore the PHP code and display the HTML file like it is displayed without any error message.
So basically my aim is to show my own error message there only if the file is not parsed by PHP.

Comment: Asking a questing then answering it immediately is not what SO should be used for

Comment: That's wrong. In fact they explicitly provide an option for this and [recommend it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).
However if you have a better answer/method or want to comment on an answer you can always do this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use this "hack". It uses an expression which is false at any time and so the HTML code is stripped of when it is parsed by PHP.
However a browser which parses this file will ignore all PHP code and therefore it always displays the HTML part.

Here is an example:

```
<?php
// only shows content when it is not parsed by a PHP interpreter
if (false):
?>
<span class="warning">
    You are viewing this file within a browser without a PHP interpreter.
    You have to access this file through PHP to show it correctly.
</span>
<?php
endif
?>
```